# PHP show MySQL table data PDO

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

I'm a PHP noob, I keep getting this error:
*Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file...*

The line it points to is at the very last line. My 'header.php' declares the !DOCTYPE html and my 'config.php' holds the database properties.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
<?php
  include 'config.php';
  include 'header.php';
?>

<div id='wrapper'>
<div style='height:50em;width:100%;z-index:10;margin-top:1em;text-align:left;'>
        <table id='mainDPUtable'>
            <th class='cen'>NUM</th>
            <th class='cen'>TYP</th>
            <th class='cen'>LVL</th>
            <th class='cen'>Job No.</th>
            <th class='cen'>Responsible</th>
            <th class='cen'>Rep</th>
            <th class='cen'>Initiated</th>
            <th class='cen'>Age</th>                
            <th class='cen'>Part Number</th>
            <th class='cen'>Qty</th>
            <th class='cen'>Description</th>
            <th class='cen'>Location</th>
            <th class='cen'>Complete</th>
        <?php
        $db = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=".$dbname.",".$user.",".$pswd);
        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $result = $db->prepare("SELECT NUM, TYP, LVL, JOBNO, RESP, REP, DATE_INITIATED, AGE, PARTNO, QTY, DESCRIPTION, LOC  FROM ".$dbtable);
        $result->execute();
        while ($row = $result->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
            $num=$row["NUM"];
            $typ=$row["TYP"];
            $lvl=$row["LVL"];
            $jobNo=$row["JOBNO"];
            $resp=$row["RESP"];
            $rep=$row["REP"];
            $date_initiated=$row["DATE_INITIATED"];
            $age=$row["AGE"];
            $partNo=$row["PARTNO"];
            $qty=$row["QTY"];
            $description=$row["DESCRIPTION"];
            $loc = $row["LOC"];     
            $comp=$row["COMP"];
        ?>
        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $num; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $typ; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $lvl; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $jobNo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $resp; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $rep; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $date_initiated; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $age; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $partNo; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $qty; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $description; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $loc; ?></td>
        <td><input type='button' id=<?php echo 'btn'.$num; ?> value='Complete'/></td>
        </tr>
        <?php}?>

        </table>
  </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Missing spaces:

```
    <?php}?>
```

should be

```
    <?php } ?>
         ^-^--
```

Comment: Yes! Thank you! When the time limit ends, I'll click the checkmark